# How can I add an event handler to the block lever in Minecraft Forge?

Tags: java, events, event-handling, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I want to add an event handling for when the player right-clicks on the lever, which means activates it. How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the `PlayerInteractEvent` and check that the type of what he is clicking equals `Material.LEVER`